# How to express "arbitrary JSON" in swagger-spec?

Tags: json, rest, swagger

Let's say I have a REST service that can accept any arbitrary JSON in the request body. How do I model this using swagger-spec?

I thought about [Model Objects](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#527-model-object), but I could only think to wrap the arbitrary JSON (as a string) within a container JSON object, like `{"payload": "{ some JSON object serialized to a string }"}`, which isn't really useful.

Or, is there some other way to express that an endpoint can receive arbitrary JSON in the request body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swagger tries to be deterministic when it comes to APIs, so what you're asking is not directly supported.

The only way I can think of to achieve what you want is to set the "consumes" property to "application/json" and add a "body" parameter of type string. This would in theory say that only JSON should be sent, but in effect, *any* string could be sent.

Also, this may break some third party tools if they'd try to convert to string to a JSON object before sending it to the server.

Comment: Makes sense, even though it's a shame.

Answer (score 7):

Model the request's body payload as `parameters` with schema of just `"type": "object"`. The swagger UI editor will then prompt the user with a large textarea containing `{}` which they can populate with a JSON object.

```
"/endpoint": {
      "post": {
        "parameters": [
          {
            "description": "Arbitrary JSON object payload",
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "object"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```